# creating new SSH keys during docker run

Tags: ssh, docker

Is there a way to generate a new SSH server key each time a container is run? I initially thought I could add this to the Dockerfile but I think this only refers to the image build process. I need a new key each time the container is run.

These is what I did to create my image.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

Comment: Best practice for container manipulation at start time is to provide a custom entry point script and a pseudo CMD. Let your entry point script do what you need, let the script run your application if the correct pseudo CMD is provided, if not run the CMD on the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
CMD /bin/rm -v /etc/ssh/ssh_host_* && dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server && /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

Answer (score 2):

Here a small example setup of a custom entry point script to dynamicly edit your container at start time.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM SOMETHING

RUN mkdir /start
ADD entrypoint.sh /start/entrypoint.sh

# set the entry point to custom script
ENTRYPOINT ["/start/entrypoint.sh"]

# define pseudo command, which is recognized by entry point script
CMD ["sshd"]
```

This copies and sets the entry point to "entrypoint.sh" and the CMD to "sshd".

Here the entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Fail fast, including pipelines
set -eo pipefail

... do your stuff like SSH key creation

if [ "$1" = 'sshd' ]; then
    exec /usr/sbin/sshd -D
fi

# if CMD is not sshd execute the CMD. 
# Good for debugging because you can pass /bin/bash for example as CMD
exec "$@"
```

Now you can gerate your ssh key at start time in the entry point script and run your application if the correct CMD is provided.

For debugging the container you can now provide "/bin/bash" for example as CMD to the docker run command. Which will give you a bash shell instead of starting your application, but your customization is still done.

Start SSHD:

```
docker run myImageName
```

Debug if entrypoint script runs correctly:

```
docker run -i -t myImageName /bin/bash
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do I need to edit the base image in the docker repo to get this to work ? i.e. the one referenced here : https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/

Comment: No but you have to place this "CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]" part of this image in your entry point script to run the sshd deamon.

Comment: Not sure if I get this. Where do I put the entrypoint.sh script. Is this just in my local filesystem ?

Comment: I changed the exmple! Now it ads the entrypoint.sh from project root and runs the ssdh in the entrypoint.sh

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this.

Comment: So based on this approach, would it be possible to only generate the new SSH keys the first time the container is run and reuse the keys for subsequent restarts ?

Comment: Sure you can implement any logic. Use too cmd values to spilt key generation from demon start. Start container for key creation, commit changes and then start the container to run the daemon. Is one approach. Or use an environment variable to control key creation etc....